# kafka broker removed from zookeeper while leader election occurs error

Tags: apache-kafka

Today I met one issue,the broker 2 is not existent in zookeeper, I thought the borker 2 is down, but it's still running well.  I checked the zookeeper log,

it only mentioned " Established session 0x153514345be0321 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client broker 2",

from the removed broker server and state-change log,

[2016-03-08 06:00:00,257] ERROR Controller 2 epoch 19 initiated state change for partition [robotEvents,186] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.StateChangeFailedException: encountered error while electing leader for partition [***,186] due to: aborted leader election for partition [****,186] since the LeaderAndIsr path was already written by another controller. This probably means that the current controller 2 went through a soft failure and another controller was elected with epoch 20..

a lot of these kind of errors occur, from the source code, this error seems normal process during leader election, but it can't explain why the broker 2 was removed from zk.   Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to restart the broker? If yes was this broker able to join the cluster? Can you tell me some more about your setup? How big is your kafka cluster? How many Zookeepers are you running?

Comment: Could you furthermore please explain how you identified that the broker was removed from the cluster? Did you checked the ZK Paths (does `brokers/id/2` exist)?

Comment: Thanks for your help, our cluster includes 3 zookeepers and 3 kafka brokers, after I got the alert message I checked the 3 brokers status, all of the 9092 ports are up running, then I went to zookeep server and used zkCli.sh list the brokers, then figoured out only borker id [0,1] exist., I restarted the missing broker, and all looks good

Comment: That sounds strange. Do you have any clue why robotEvents,186 went offline? Were there any network issues?
As far as I know the broker nodes (on zookeeper) are ephmeral nodes. So as soon as the connection to ZK is broken this nodes disapear.

Comment: I checked the LAN network, the other servers all worked well, there might be issue on this broker. I checked the app log at that time,